# How do I surround my line of text with tags?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2017, trying to do a search and replace using regular expressions to do the following. I would like to surround each line in my text file with `<li>line</li>`

For example:

```
This is line 1 to be surrounded with list item tags
This is line 2 to be surrounded with list item tags
This is line 3 to be surrounded with list item tags
```

The desired output

```
<li>This is line 1 to be surrounded with list item tags</li>
<li>This is line 2 to be surrounded with list item tags</li>
<li>This is line 3 to be surrounded with list item tags</li>
```

I've tried the following:

search: `^.*$`
replace: `<li>$1</li>`
result is:

```
<li>$1</li>
<li>$1</li>
<li>$1</li>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Where is the capture group in your regex which $1 should refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding parenthesis around the regex that you are using to search

search: `(^.*$)`
replace `<li>$1</li>`

If you wanted to have a second substitution it would need another set of parenthesis around the "search" regex

Comment: That includes line breaks \r in the capture group.

Comment: you are right in pointing out that the regex for the search is not correct, however in his case it seems he is stuck on the printing of the literal `$1`

Comment: This is what I needed. But I would like to know how not to include the \r?

Comment: @Rod, try `^(.*)\r?$`. Note that the \r is now outside the capture group. (Also look here for some more info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio , especially about the end line anchor)

Answer (score 0):

search for: `^([^\r\n]+?)(\r?\n?)$`

replace with: `<li>$1</li>$2`

Comment: this will require you to have a new line on the last line of the file

Comment: This is just ... weird.